# Set Host in Redirect?

Tags: http, redirect, http-headers, host

We have shared virtual hosting on our server which is able to map requests to the correct domain directory based on the "Host" HTTP header that is provided in the request. I am able to cURL directly to the IP address if I provide that "Host" header.

Something like the following:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "127.0.0.1");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Host: example.com"));
...
```

This is useful because the current site lives at a different IP address and I can reach our development site through IP address (without having to touch any "hosts" file or something similar).

My question: **is it possible to provide that "Host" header through a simple HTTP redirect too (that the browser can then use when it makes its next 'GET' request)?** - something like:

```
<?php

// this clearly doesn't work
header("Location: http://{$server_public_ip_address}/");
header("Host: example.com");
exit;
```

I realize being able to do something like this could be a large security hazard to front end users but it made me curious if there was an easier way to redirect all of our dev traffic to our dev site without having to:  cURL it all up, or adjust hosts files, or move the site, or enable dedicated IP addresses..

It's probably not possible but I can't find any definitive answer on Google.

*Even if an .htaccess file rewrite could do it, that would be great, but I doubt that that's possible either.*

Comment: just make separate domain name for development setup , i.e. ```dev.example.com``` and use it without any workarounds in whatever clients (curl, browser, etc)

Comment: Did I understand correct, There are no DNS-entries that bind the hostnames to the specific IP (A-Record) ?

Comment: Thanks @MaximSagaydachny that is one of the techniques we currently use - just looking to learn more about HTTP and its possibilities :)

Comment: @johnSmith right - we can do that (if we have access to the client's DNS) but I am just curious if it's possible to point the browser somewhere else based on your HTTP response without the browser looking to your 'hosts' file, or 'DNS cache' or out to the public  DNS server.

Comment: hmn AFAIK the browser will always try to resolve the hostname with DNS, but cant you just do sth like:  `header("Location: /");header("Host: example.com");` ?

Comment: thanks @johnSmith I'm trying to not use the FQDN in the host - I'm trying to use the IP address

Comment: @johnSmith (sorry I mis-spoke) - I'm trying to tell the browser the IP address and Host at the same time - to prevent it from looking up the IP address itself - I've got a few more tests but I'm almost certain the answer is no - and there's already a lot of alternative ways to accomplish the same thing